# how to add ringtone or vibrate notifications for post and messages in android scringo social networking app?

Tags: android, eclipse, scringo

i am using SCRINGO SDK in my android app....following are the screenshot for my app.. it is working fine but i am not getting notification when someone post , like or comment an activity , user messages .. i want to setup up alert ringtone or vibrate notification for that app so even when any user who is registered to the app got notifications on home screen with vibrate or alert tone (like ... user 4 likes your post.. you have a new message from user 2)...

i have tried using gcm services but its not working ... i have produced the app on google cloud got the project number and api key added it in scringo's dashboard.. and edited the mainfest but m not getting the desired result.... following is my mainfest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
package="com.scringo.friendz" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<permission android:name="com.scringo.friendz.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"  android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.scringo.friendz.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<permission android:name="com.scringo.friendz.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.scringo.friendz.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >

    <receiver android:name="com.scringo.push.ScringoGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
    <category android:name="com.scringo.friendz"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.scringo.push.ScringoGCMIntentService"/>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.scringo.friendz.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.scringo.push.ScringoGCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.scringo.scringosample" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.scringo.friendz.MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.scringo.LoginBroadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.scringo.push.ScringoGCMIntentService" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBx8aj7JrKh-rQAD96FgeAlf8-XFLc4ELc"/>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/title_activity_image_view"
        android:name="com.scringo.friendz.ImageViewActivity" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you designated an IP address when setting up your server key (the instructions say to leave it blank, thus allowing all IPs)?

I followed the instructions provided by Scringo [here](http://www.scringo.com/docs/android-guides/popular/setup-push-notifications/) exactly as written, and after successfully sending a test push message I started getting new message alerts when another user messaged me.